# Can you join a minyan in another room?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan, chassidic-rebbe

I recently davened (prayed) at a hassidic Rebbe's minyan. I found something peculiar, namely that the Rebbe didn't actually daven in the same room as everyone else. Instead, he davened in a different room **with the door closed at all times**. To indicate that he had completed shmoneh esrei there was a knock or sound that came from his room. After asking I was told that he always davens like this and other hassidic Rebbes do as well. I would like to know what the halachic basis is for this practice and are there any other sects of Judaism that do things similarly?

Answer (score 4):

See Shulchan Aruch Horav ([OC 55:22](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/6/55/22), [591:14](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/2/591)) where he says that if  there is 10 people in the room then anyone, in another room/house, who hears them could be Yotse with them.

Comment: The issue is does it count as tefillah betzibbur not can you answer them

Comment: @Double AA, see here http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/sh/sh4/2/591

Comment: I couldn't fix it so I'll add it's in Seif 14